# Solving for length of an unknown side of a triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles, congruences, angle, congruences-geometry

I have been given the figure below:

[Figure (click me).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTTyG.jpg)

I know that $AD=20-x$ and $m\angle ACD=m\angle BCD$. How can I set up a ratio also knowing that $AC=11$ and $BC=14$ in order to find $x$? Thanks!

Comment: AD/AC = BD/BC  why?

Comment: @DougM It's because $m\angle ACD= m\angle BCD$. What is the name of this property?

Comment: @Emery It's angle bisector theorem.

Answer (score 1):

We can write:
$$\dfrac{S_{\Delta ACD}}{S_{\Delta CDB}}=\dfrac{AD}{BD}$$
And Also:
$$\dfrac{S_{\Delta ACD}}{S_{\Delta CDB}}=\dfrac{CD\cdot CA\cdot\sin(\angle ACD)}{CD\cdot CB\cdot \sin(\angle BCD)}=\dfrac{CA}{CB}$$
So we can conclude:
$$\dfrac{AD}{BD}=\dfrac{CA}{CB}\Rightarrow\dfrac{20-x}{x}=\dfrac{11}{14}$$

And so on.